# How do I copy a .kext file to the extensions folder

Tags: macos

I want to change `vmmon.kext` in `/System/Library/Extensions/`, and I run

```
$ sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/vmmon.kext
```

but

```
$ sudo cp -pR /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/kexts/vmmon.kext /System/Library/Extensions/
```

doesn't work

```
cp: /System/Library/Extensions/vmmon.kext: Read-only file system
...
```

I've tried

1. `sudo kextunload /Users/mac/Desktop/vmmon.kext` but get

```
(kernel) Kext com.vmware.kext.vmx86 not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.vmware.kext.vmx86 - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

2. `sudo chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Extensions/*` but Operation not permitted

It is ridiculous, macOS doesn't allow me to do anything, but allow me to delete it!

Comment: You probably need to disable `SIP` before you can muck around in those directories.

Answer (score -1):

chflags nouchg file
open folder configuration and change permissions